# Degrees of Polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there any ring $A$ such that in  $A[x]$, some polynomial of degree 2 is equal to a polynomial of degree 4?

I am thinking no, because of the division algorithm states at $a(x) = b(x)q(x) + r(x)$ where the degree of $r(x) <$ the degree of $b(x)$

but am not sure

Comment: What division algoritm? $A[x]$ needs not be Euclidean, if $A$ is not a field. Namely, $A=\Bbb Z$, $a(x)=x^2$ and $b(x)=2x$ do not satisfy $a(x)=b(x)q(x)+r(x)$ for any $\deg r<1$.

Comment: If there were, then it would not make sense to talk about the degree of a polynomial in $A[x]$, but degree is always well-defined in $A[x]$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. In the ring of polynomials two polynomials are *defined* to be equal iff their coefficients agree, and degree of a polynomial is the largest $k$ for which the coefficient of $x^k$ is nonzero...